# How do I keep the divs side by side in the container?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to create container that has two elements with colors given in the picture.  The two are different divs and must stay side by side.  How do I do it?

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <style>
   .container{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
   }
   .sidenav{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
   }
   .bgrnd{
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="sidenav">
   </div>
   <div class="bgrnd">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How about this:

<div class="container">
   <div class="sidenav">
      test
   </div>
   <div class="bgrnd">
      test
   </div>
</div>

CSS:

.container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
.sidenav {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}
.bgrnd {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't set a height on the body of the document so setting a percentage on the divs won't do anything until you do. You also needed to float the sidenav div.

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.sidenav {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  float: left
}

.bgrnd {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidenav">
  </div>
  <div class="bgrnd">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code Updated!

```css
    body, html{ 
      padding:0px; 
      margin:0px; 
      height:100%;
    }

    .container{
      width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
    }
  
    .sidenav{
   width: 25%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: black;
   float: left;
     }
     
 .bgrnd{
   width: 75%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: blue;
      float: left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidenav"></div>
  <div class="bgrnd"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `.sidenav` and `.bgrnd` to `position: absolute;` and position them accordingly from there. Also, you've set `.container` to: `width: 50%;` and `height: 50%;` which I presume you don't want.

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidenav {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
.bgrnd {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidenav"></div>
    <div class="bgrnd"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using css-flex.

```
#main {
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
-webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse; /* Safari 6.1+ */
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.div1 {
width: 25%;
height: 50px;
}
.div2 {
width: 75%;
height: 50px;
}
<div id="main">
  <div class="div1" style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div class="div2" style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
</div>
```